# WPF TextBox ugly borders problem

Tags: wpf, textbox, border

I want to override the default TextBox borders in WPF. I have this style that applies on all TextBoxes.

```
<!-- StyleTextBox-->
<Style x:Key="StyleTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{DynamicResource WriteAble}"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFont_DarkGray}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!--Resolves multiline textbox vertical alignment problem-->
        <Trigger Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I added `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` to display borders correctly on LCD monitors.

But, every TextBox seems to be different. Some borders are missing, or gray.. 
Does anyone know why?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the effect in XamlPad. Can you be more specific about it? Like show the rest of your markup; and a screenshot would possibly help, too.

Comment: looks okay, just donn specify width property to Textbox...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try editing the template for the textboxes and changing the border name *Bd* to a "real" border instead of the chrome one. Like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxBaseControlTemplate1" 
          TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
  <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" 
              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
  </Border>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
      <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" 
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" 
           Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

add this setter to your style to enable the template:

```
<Setter Property="Template" 
        Value="{DynamicResource TextBoxBaseControlTemplate1}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally a working solution ! U rock man!

Comment: This is such a simple answer I want to slap myself. Kudos to you.

Answer (score 2):

WPF tries to be device independent when rendering UI to the monitor, and won't draw things "pixel perfect" unless you tell it to. Try adding this to your style:

```
<Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
```

That should tell WPF to render each 1-pixel-thick border along a single pixel line.

Comment: I tried without success :-( Those TextBoxes are placed in a Grid. Could it be a problem? But for majority of TextBoxes I set Width="Auto" or Width="*" .. so I don't see the point of hiding.

Comment: Hmm. Having the TextBoxes in a grid shouldn't be a problem. Can you update your question with the complete style definition?

Answer (score 0):

You need do the followings to solve that problem...

1. `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"`
2. Dont specify width, do it with the margins

   `<Setter Property="BorderBrush" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,2,2,2" 
   Value="{StaticResource DarkGray}" />`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hmm. I've already tried everything. I think that the problem ought be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the left border and upper border is styled, but the right and buttom border stays gray, although I explicitly said in Style that BorderBrush=MyBrush.
What do you think? What about to try remove the **3D effect** from TextBox?

Comment: Try reducing the textbox width and height... observe any changes